# Centering images in Bigcartel

Tags: html, css, web, bigcartel

on my website [here](http://pafclub.bigcartel.com/1) I have an image that is originally 2315 × 3274. What I would like to do is get the image to center on every device, so far I have gotten my image to center on my laptop but when looking at it on my desktop it isn't centered at all. horizontal centering is the preferred option but both horizontal and vertical is the best outcome. Here is the code

Thanks

```css
#1 .page {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<p>
<a href="/2"><br>
  <img style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;max-width: 3274px;display:block;margin-right: -150px" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/bdd0c10a55.jpg" alt="1"><br>
</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Add `text-align: center` to `p`. Try changing `<p>` to `<p style="text-align: center">`

Comment: Just remove that margin-right!

Comment: when removing margin right it just goes back to the left, also text align doesn't do anything either, have added the text align code nd removed the margin code http://pafclub.bigcartel.com/1.

Comment: You can't use `#1` to reference the id of the `<body`> tag because it's invalid CSS. You may want to consider changing your page names to something like "Page 1", "Page 2", etc or "One", "Two", "Three" so you can identify them by ID. Then the code you provided should work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to set the image as background.
On the place of `<img ... />` Add the following:

HTML

`<div class="img-responsive"></div>`

CSS

`.img-responsive{
    background: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/bdd0c10a55.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-attachment: relative;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;/* or any that you want */
    /*-webkit-background-size: 90%; can be used to control the image size*/
}`

Comment: by making the image background will it still be able to be click?

Comment: Yes, like this `<a href="link"><div class="img-responsive"></div></a>`

Comment: unfortunately still doesn't make it in the middle of the screen it still stays to the left.